# How can a mechanical linkage with a closed loop be rigged?

Tags: animation, armature, rigging

I'm trying to rig a model of a Peaucellier-Lipkin mechanical linkage.  While inverse kinematics for a chain of bones in the armature works well for some of the linkage, I don't see how to create the closed loop portion.  There must be some way to constrain the tails of two bones to stay together, but I am having trouble finding it.

Here's what I have so far.

[image: Screenshot of Blender 2.69 with armature for PLL]

Comment: I wonder if non-rigging method is acceptable? If so, I can suggest a better one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are generally two ways here: **bone constraints** and **rigidbody simulation**.

### Solution 1 - Bone Constraints:

---

1. Create the linkages (meshes).
2. Create armature with bones set as shown on the image below.
3. Animate the key bone (the red one here).
4. Rigging.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Result:

[image]

Example file: [image]

### Solution 2 - Rigidbody Simulation:

---

1. Build the initial state of the linkage, make sure they don't intersect or too close to each other;
2. Select them all, click **Add Active** button in Physics tab in Toolshelf;
3. Select either two linkages, click **Connect** in that tab to create constraints, set type to **Hinge**, move them to expected hinge points. Note that Hinge rotates along the Z axis of constraints (empty objects), so you may need to correct the rotation.
4. Create rotation action for BoneEB (the blue bone in the image below), toggle **Animated** in its Rigid Body setting panel.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

For better result, you need to set the *Steps per Second* and *Solver Iterations* relatively high in **Scene** tab.

Result:

[image]

Example file:[image]

Comment: That's cool! Can you provide some details about how you did that?

Comment: @Matt OK. See the updated answer.

Comment: Why are the Steps Per Second and Iterations so high?

Comment: @Vader I think there are some loop constraints, which needs more accurate calculation in this case. I've tried not to do so, but the result is weird.

Comment: Great!  I started looking at rigid body physics, too, but I didn't get very far.  Building on what you've done, someday, I'd like to write some Python to output the coordinates of the empty at D as a function of the rotation of the blue arm.

Comment: I was trying to animate a Scott Russell linkage and your post got me headed in the right directions. I then followed some introductory video tutorials by Neal Hirsig on Blender Righd Bodies and was eventually able to produce the animation shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIS5H9sDgvA
However I think that my approach is rather 'clunky' and I'd like to better understand step 4 in your answer. Could you please explain in more detail exactly what you mean by "Create rotation action for BoneEB" Do you literally mean a bone as in part of an armature?

Comment: @MichaelGordon Luckily I found it somewhere. See the updated file link.