# Suspend object with ropes on two pivots

Tags: physics

I want to manipulate an object on two pivots.
Think of it as a long piece of something that is suspended by two pieces of rope. And i I pull up the rope on one side, that end of the object goes up.

[image: two ropes pulling an object from two pivots]

I know how to simulate the visual impression of that using rotation and movement. But as it is a simulation of an actual physical process I would like to solve it using only the two upper ends of my ropes.
So I was hanging long wiry objects as soft body or cloth from my manipulating Emties, connecting another Empty on each lower end, It's dangling just fine. But how do i now connect those two lower "knots" to my object so it will freely react to the hight of each rope's upper point?

I was also trying to go this direction. But that only lifted one side of the object with no rotation.
I feel like I don't really look in the right direction. Thank You guys for the help!

Comment: Do you need the actual physical simulation, or is the mechanical aspect enough? It might be easier to just use an armature and rig the contraption

Comment: I'm afraid it has to be a physical simulation. I need to know the position and rotation if I pull the upper end of one of the rope straight up. If I just rotate the object itself the changes in angle and the "pull" distance don't translate properly.

Comment: OK, since all the physical approaches didn't work out, I'm going with a highly inaccurate but fast and simple solution...
An Empty being the upper end of rope 1 for the #1reference hight, parent another empty as the lower end, parenting the actual object to that lower end and then using a "track to" constraint to the "lower end"-empty of rope 2 that is parented to an empty as the upper end of rope 2 and thuis presenting the reference hight for the second rope. 
It will not regard gravity inn any way, but it's the only solution I came up with ... Unless one of You knows a more accurate way.

Comment: Te physical part I was asking about was just the dangling motion or any swinging you might get. If all you want is the mechanical aspect of it, since pulling a rope up or down as a linear correlation to the position of the bar then simple constraints might be more than enough.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7372/how-can-a-mechanical-linkage-with-a-closed-loop-be-rigged/7519#7519

Comment: So far it’s fine. But at some point I need to incorporate the extra vectors of gravity and the resulting horizontal movement.