# Animating a train pantograph

Tags: animation, rigging

I tried to animate a pantograph just for fun, but it didn't  work. I have tried lot of ideas particularly with the observation of these pages:

- [How can a mechanical linkage with a closed loop be rigged?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7372/how-can-a-mechanical-linkage-with-a-closed-loop-be-rigged)
- https://blenderartists.org/t/animating-a-rigid-linkage/685592

The best result I obtain is this one :

[image: Pantograph lowered]

But there is still a mistake, the pantograph bow does not keep a vertical position.
The root bone to make the animation is this one selected on the picture.

The perfect movement is here :
https://youtu.be/w_9YgDjfohc?t=55

[image]

Here is the Blend file: http://www.wfr.zone/w/blender_animation_images/pantographe_pli%C3%A9.blend

---

It seems that it should be a perfect four-bar linkage in order to work.
I have try with linkage2 software, and the result show that the cross bar move not vertically with accuracy :

[image: linkage for a pantogoraph]

But Blender seems to be able to tolerate such imperfection, no ?

---

It seems that it should be a perfect four-bar linkage in order to work.
I have try with linkage2 software, and the result show that the cross bar move not vertically with accuracy :

[image: linkage for a pantogoraph]

But Blender seems to be able to tolerate such imperfection, no ?

Comment: can u show/link a video how it is supposed to work? thanks.

Comment: The perfect movement is here : https://youtu.be/w_9YgDjfohc
Thank's

Comment: Thank's @Jachym Michal ! How do you make a gif so easy like this ?

Comment: Hey :). Screen capture with [Licecap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/). I often add gifs in my answers :))